# Function returning null causing application crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

We have a function that iterates an array with default value of of **null**. 
The function works fine when given a value, but if given the default value of null the application crashes instead of returning the else statement (placeholder image)

output:
***> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null***

```
  const doesPersonHaveImage = (imageSource?: any) => {
    if (imageSource !== null) {
      return <img src={"data:image/gif;base64," + imageSource} alt="" />
    } else {
      return <img src={PlaceHolderImage} alt="" />
    }
  }
```

Comment: That error tells me that somewhere, you're accessing `imageSource.data`. I don't see that in the snippet you posted, so you may need to post more of your code to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Your code looks fine. where's the property 'data'? maybe the error is coming from elsewhere?